# Parse.com Error: Too many recursive calls into Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm just trying to create a basic recursive function that returns a result once it reaches a certain number. However I keep getting this error. Anyone have any ideas whats wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
GLOBAL = {};
GLOBAL.cnt = 0; 

Parse.Cloud.define('recursiveTest', function(request, response)
{       
    GLOBAL.cnt++;

    if(GLOBAL.cnt >= 2) {
        response.success(GLOBAL.cnt);   
    }   

    request = {};

    Parse.Cloud.run('recursiveTest', request, response);        
});
```

Here is the full error:

> {"code":141,"error":"{\"code\":141,\"message\":\"{\\"code\\":141,\\"message\\":\\"{\\\\"code\\\\":141,\\\\"message\\\\":\\\\"{\\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\\":141,\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":124,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Too many recursive calls into Cloud Code\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\"}\\\\"}\\"}\"}"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out somewhat of a workaround. It works in my situation at least:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('recursiveTest', function(request, response)
{   
    function doRecursive(cnt)
    {               
        cnt++;

        if(cnt >= 2) {
            response.success(cnt);   
        }       
    }   

    doRecursive(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is infinitely recursive. Maybe you wanted to do this?

```
Parse.Cloud.define('recursiveTest', function(request, response)
{       
    GLOBAL.cnt++;

    if(GLOBAL.cnt >= 2) {
        // added `return` here
        return response.success(GLOBAL.cnt);   
    }   

    request = {};

    // added `return` here
    return Parse.Cloud.run('recursiveTest', request, response);        
});
```

In any case, you have to `return` to terminate the recursion at some point, since otherwise the function will run forever (or practically until you get a too much recursion error) without ever delivering the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just deployed your code changes and I still get the same error. Something is telling me that Cloud Code doesn't support Global variables? Though it's not officially (or unofficially) documented anywhere and Parse.com support takes longer than apple to respond (average of 5 days - never). Any workaround ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure how Parse's system is set up, but if you are defining a cloud function, it seems like the code will not run in the same scope that it was defined in. It seems to me that the function will be sent as a string to their server, which is where the code will ultimately be run. If this is true, cloud functions will not have access to your local scope. You could pass in your `GLOBAL` parameter, or you could use Parse's database to store `GLOBAL.cnt`'s value.